# Testing dynamically created methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

In my model, I dynamically create some methods based on database records:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job_status

  # Adds #requisition?, #open?, #paused?, #closed?
  class_eval do    
    JobStatus.all.each do |status|
      unless method_defined? "#{status.name.downcase}?"
        define_method("#{status.name.downcase}?") do 
          job_status_id == status.id
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class JobStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
end
```

The `job_statuses` table contains some seed data, so is not going to be frequently changing, but in case I ever need to add new statuses, I don't have to add more code to get a boolean method for the new status.

However, I am not sure how to test these methods, because when rspec starts the `job_statuses` table is obviously empty, and when the `JobStatus` objects are created, `Job` gets initialized, but since no objects exist yet, it doesn't create any methods, and my tests fail because the methods don't exist.

Note that I am using rspec with spork & guard, and using database-cleaner with the truncation strategy (as per [Railscast #257](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara), since I'm using Selenium), so that probably complicates matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to abstract the creation of runtime methods out into a library file, and then in my test file, remove and redeclare my class before each test, and reload the actual class (and blueprints) at the end of the suite:

```
describe AssociationPredicate do
  before(:all) do
    ["Continuous", "Standard"].each { |type| JobType.create!(:job_type => type) }
    ["Requisition", "Open", "Paused", "Closed"].each { |status| JobStatus.create!(:job_status => status) }
  end

  after(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation, :only => %w( job_types job_statuses )

    # Reload Job model to remove changes
    Object.send(:remove_const, 'Job')
    load 'job.rb'
    load 'support/blueprints.rb'
  end

  before(:each) do
    Object.send(:remove_const, 'Job')

    # Redefine Job model for testing purposes
    class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to  :job_type
      belongs_to  :job_status

      has_many    :job_applications
    end
  end

  it "should add methods when included" do
    Job.send(:association_predicate, :job_type)
    job.should respond_to(:continuous?)
    job.should respond_to(:standard?)
  end
end
```

This way, I create a basic class for each test, add the runtime methods as necessarily, and return to the actual class when I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

Try with *[enumerize](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize)* gem. This make your status field like enumerator and build the "#{status.name.downcase}?" for your models. *[This gem](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize)* came with it's own rspec-matchers making easiest your unit test.